# Не отрабатывает artisan db:seed

Tags: mysql, laravel

Сайт на Laravel. Клонирую проект с библиотеки git для работы локально.
Файл `.env` с настройками создал. Прописал пользователя, базу и пароль для входа. 
Команда `php artisan key:generate` отрабатывает, ключ прописывается.

```
php artisan migrate
```

отрабатывает без ошибок, таблица мигрейтов в базе создается, все остальные таблицы тоже.
Но когда отдается команда

```
php artisan db:seed
```

При выполнении первого сида сразу выдает ошибку:

```
Seeding: AdvantagesSeeder

[LengthException]                       
Cannot get 1 elements, only 0 in array
```

База данных представляет собой просто мигрейт болванку с пустыми таблицами. Сидеры прикладываю. Гугление толком ничего не дало.

Основной databaseseeder.php

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
 /**
  * Run the database seeds.
  *
  * @return void
  */
 public function run()
 {
  File::delete(File::allFiles(public_path('images/tmp')));

  $this->call(AdvantagesSeeder::class);
  $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
  $this->call(ArticlesTableSeeder::class);
  $this->call(SlidesTableSeeder::class);
  $this->call(FeedbacksSeeder::class);
  $this->call(PagesTableSeeder::class);
  $this->call(WholesalersTableSeeder::class);
  $this->call(SettingsTableSeeder::class);
  $this->call(CatalogSeeder::class);
  $this->call(ArticlesTableSeeder::class);
  $this->call(OrdersSeeder::class);
 }
}
```

Ну и для образца сидер на котором вылетает. Но я думаю проблема в другом. Может библиотеку какую не доставил.

```html
<?php

class AdvantagesSeeder extends \Illuminate\Database\Seeder
{

 /**
  * @inheritdoc
  */
 public function run()
 {
  \App\Models\Advantage::truncate();

  factory(\App\Models\Advantage::class, 4)->create();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, недоделка прошлого программиста. Был описан метод добавления рандомных картинок из папки images, но путь был неправильный, в каждом из несрабатывающих сидеров было обращение к этому методу, вот все и крашилось.